# NSIS Installer does not show Russian text

Tags: localization, nsis, cyrillic, modern-ui, windows-mui

I am trying to create an installer that support Russian language. I spent many times, but still did not fix the problem.

I have Windows 10 English version with installed Russian language pack. Russian language is set to default.

Here are my steps:

1. Install NSIS 3.01. (The same was with 2.46).
2. Build Examples\languages.nsi from NSIS. I use Windows XP as build PC.

When I run languages.exe on Window 10 and select Russian language I see the following:

[image]

The text is not in Russian.
Well it is probably in Russian, but in wrong font. Otherwise all text consist of question character (?).

With "Unicode true", the text is in Russian. But I would not like to use it and to understand the issue.

Regards,
Valery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are still supporting Windows 95/98/ME there is no reason to not build a Unicode installer.

You must change the [Language for non-Unicode programs](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/int_pr_select_language_version.mspx?mfr=true) to make non-Unicode version display the correct characters.

Comment: 1. Your are right. My program was built in VC6.0 with UNICODE and it shows Russian. That is why I could not understand when NSIS installer did not show Russian. I changed language for non-Unicode programs and that fixed my issue. 2. I also could build my NSIS installer with unicode support. I have some ansi 3rdparty dll and they did not work with unicode installer. I found CallAnsiPlugin. My software does not support 9X/ME, so I agree with you to use unicode installer. Thanks for your both variants.